# How to remove every node from ArKit sceneview and free up memory

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, sceneview

Here is my code:
It removes the nodes, but the memory is still around 200MB

```
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, _) in
   if node.name == path! {
       node.removeFromParentNode()
   }
}
```

Comment: This 'may' help you: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15999